# Using 'this.'. How to access JavaScript object properties in different ways

Tags: javascript, oop, web-applications, properties, gis

men, i'm stuck in one easy thing: I know two ways of implementing my JavaScript 'programm', but there's one problem. Imagine, we have a constructor for some object, for ex.:

```
function Map () {
    //and this object has some properties
    this.foo = 'bar';
};
```

Now we create an instance of this object:

```
var myMap = new Map ();
```

I need to implement a procedure which will draw a new vector layer for this 'Map', and it *should use property 'foo'*. I can do it, implementing it as a 'Map' method, like:

```
Map.prototype.layer = function () {
    ...;//some uninteresting code
    this.foo += 'bar';
};
```

'this.foo' in this context means Map.foo, that's i need, ok, now I can write

```
MyMap.layer ();//and this will draw my layer
```

But what if implement it not like a method, but like a constructor which will *create new* layer instance? something, that we could use this way:

```
var myLayer = new myMap.Layer ();
```

How i should write the constructor for it? Like

```
Map.prototype.Layer = function () {
//and how to access Map.foo now?
//if i write 'this.foo' here
//and then call this constructor like i wrote above
//it will mean 'Map.Layer.foo', isn't it?
};
```

Where am I wrong? How to define a constructor for a 'Layer' object which should be a property of 'Map' object and use 'Map's properties?

Comment: any reason why do you want to do it this way ?

Comment: Why should `Layer` depend on `myMap`?

Comment: i imagine this way is effective for further work with 'layers'. We will be able to do like this:  `var myLayer = myMap.Layer ();    myLayer.makeVisible; myLayer.addVector  //and so on...` Actually, i look on Leaflet library for map creating. I need to write something more simpler just to drawing vector maps on screen.

Comment: you can always do it if myLayer extends myMap wherein all properties of map would be available to the layer.

Comment: Is there any reason why do you add constructor as a method on another constructor prototype ?? why not using inheritance? and you can bind this with call, apply or bind methods

Comment: Hmm. If an objectA is the property of objectB -- how may I access from objectA the other properties of B ?